# looping through two dataframes to find matches in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have two dataframes: `dataframe_x` and `dataframe_y` now i want to loop through both of them at the same time to check if `dataframe_x` `vector_x_2` matches `vector_y_1` from `dataframe_y` if so i want the matched row from `dataframe_y` in my `dataframe_x`. Right now my loop only tries to fills the 3rd column which is `vector_y_1` but ideally it would copy the whole row into `dataframe_x`.

This is the code I came up with Code:

```
vector_x_1 <- c("Max.1","Max.1","Max.2")
vector_x_2 <- c("BX.1","BX.6","BX.5")
dataframe_x <- data.frame(cbind(vector_x_1,vector_x_2))

vector_y_1 <- c("BX.1","BX.3","BX.3","BX.10","BX.15")
vector_y_2 <- c("9,90","9,80","9,80", "7,90", "4,70")
vector_y_3 <- c("A","B","C", "D", "E")
vector_y_4 <- 1:5
dataframe_y <- data.frame(cbind(vector_y_1,vector_y_2, vector_y_3,vector_y_4))

dataframe_x <- dataframe_x %>% mutate("vector_y_1"="","vector_y_2"="","vector_y_3"="","vector_y_4"="")

for (i in nrow(dataframe_x)) {
  for (k in nrow(dataframe_y)) {
    if(dataframe_x[i,2] == dataframe_y[k,1]) {
      dataframe_x[i,3] <- dataframe_y[k,1]
    }
    else {
      dataframe_x[i,3] <- "no match"
    }
  }
}
```

This is probably a really basic question but i do not understand why my loops are not working.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You just need to merge, `merge(df_x, df_y,  by.x = 'vector_x_2', by.y = 'vector_y_1')`

Comment: Or use `match` : `cbind(dataframe_x, dataframe_y[match(dataframe_x$vector_x_2, dataframe_y$vector_y_1),])`